# On the notion of stochastic derivative

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

In order to prove Ito's lemma, one of the basic requirements to be made is assuming the function $f(X_t, t)$ to be (at least) twice differentiable.
In this way, $f$ can be expanded via a Taylor series.

But what does it mean differentiability with respect to a random process $X_t$?
Should $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f(X_t,t)}{\partial{X_t}}$ be seen as
$$
\lim_{dt\to0}\frac{f(X_{t+dt},t)-f(X_t,t)}{X_{t+dt}-X_t}?
$$
If yes, in what sense? In probability? In distribution?...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it means that the real valued function $f$ should be differintiable, i.e. $\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}$ should exist for all $x$.  The requirement $$\lim_{dt \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(X_{t+dt},t)-f(X_t,t)}{X_{t+dt}-X_t}$$ exists would be far too restrictive, and would rule out even functions like $f(X_t,t) = X_t$ for a lot of stochastic processes.

Comment: suppose $f$ is the identity function, which is differentiable everywhere. On the other hand, the Wiener process, which can be seen as the identity function applied to it, is nowhere differentiable... isn't this contradictory?

Comment: @ric.san No, what is contradictory about it?  What I wrote above says that we just need $f(x,t)$ to be differentiable, not $f(X_t,t)$ to be differentiable.  The identity function is even the example I used to show that that assumption would be too strong.